# Suddenly users don't get to consent to Microsoft app privileges

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I recently made some changes to our Microsoft App that is being used for a mobile application. Upon the oauth2 login the users should be able to consent to the stuff we are asking for. But recently the users don't get this question anymore - and are instead logged in directly. Why could this be?

[image: The rights that are given to the app]

Our company administrator has given his consent to us using these permissions, but i think we might have accidently added something that just skips the asking step for all users.

#### While logging in

While logging in we are with the request - sending this scope to Microsoft:

- User.ReadWrite
- Mail.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.Read.Shared
- Offline_access

Could it be any rights here that messes with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Once a user has provided consent, why would you want to ask them _again_?

Comment: Have you ever consented permissions in the app registration (preview)? You should check the permissions consent in the app registration (preview).